# Send Email After Record Update PHP

Tags: php, mysql, email

i'm trying to send email to both user and admin after remaining amount successfully paid, record is updating but can't getting the email on both receiver using object oriented php for email here is my code

```
include("config.php");
include('Email.php');
session_start();

// Declair Veriables

$receiver   = $_SESSION['enrollment_email'];
$receiver2  = "admin@icifb.org";
$username   = $_SESSION['session_fname']." ".$_SESSION['session_lname'];
$studentid  = $_SESSION['studentSeccID'];

$view_content   =   "SELECT * FROM wp_enrollment_info WHERE enrollment_id='$studentid'";
$rs             =   mysql_query($view_content);
$content_rows   =   mysql_fetch_array($rs); 


    $i_email    = $_SESSION['enrollment_email'];    
    $i_rem      = $_SESSION['temp_remaining'];
    $i_paid     = $_SESSION['temp_paid'];

    $query      = mysql_query("UPDATE wp_enrollment_info SET enrollment_paidEnroll=enrollment_paidEnroll+'$i_paid', enrollment_remBalance='$i_rem' WHERE enrollment_email='$i_email'");

    $res        = mysql_insert_id();

    $sqlurow    =   mysql_affected_rows($query);

    if($sqlurow>0)
    {
    // Prepare Email Body Text

$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "<tr>";
$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "<td bgcolor='#FAFAFA' style='padding:15px;'>";
$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "<h4 style='font-family:Verdana; font-size:13px;'>Dear ".$_SESSION['session_fname']." ".$_SESSION['session_lname']."</h4>";
$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "<p style='font-family:Verdana; font-size:12px;'>You have successfully paid your remaining amount.</p>";
$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "<br />";
$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "<h4 style='font-family:Verdana; font-size:13px;'><u>Below is the Payment Detail:</u></h4>";
$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "<p style='font-family:Verdana; font-size:12px;'><strong>Total Amount Paid: </strong>£".$content_rows['enrollment_paidEnroll']."</p>";
$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "<br />";
$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "<p style='font-family:Verdana; font-size:12px; text-align:justify; line-height: 20px;'>If you have any query with respect to payments please contact us at <a href='mailto:admin@icifb.org'>admin@icifb.org</a></p>";

// Prepare Email Body2 Text
$EmailBody2 = $EmailBody2 . "<tr>";
$EmailBody2 = $EmailBody2 . "<td bgcolor='#FAFAFA' style='padding:15px;'>";
$EmailBody2 = $EmailBody2 . "<h4 style='font-family:Verdana; font-size:13px;'>Dear Admin</h4>";
$EmailBody2 = $EmailBody2 . "<p style='font-family:Verdana; font-size:12px;'>The following student paid due amount.</p>";
$EmailBody2 = $EmailBody2 . "<br />";
$EmailBody2 = $EmailBody2 . "<p style='font-family:Verdana; font-size:12px;'><strong>Name: </strong>".$_SESSION['session_fname']." ".$_SESSION['session_lname']."</p>";
$EmailBody2 = $EmailBody2 . "<p style='font-family:Verdana; font-size:12px;'><strong>Total Amount Paid: </strong>£".$content_rows['enrollment_paidEnroll']."</p>";

// redirect to contact us page
$email = new Email();

if ($email->send6($EmailBody,$receiver))
{

    $email->send6($EmailBody2,$receiver2);
}
    }
```

please review my code and suggest me a better way of doing it

**Email.php**

```
public function send6($EmailBodyParam,$receiver)
{
    // Email Body

$sendername     =   "ICIFB | Finance Department";
$sender         =   "payments@icifb.org";
$Subject        =   "Payment Confirmation";

$EmailBody  = "<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='800'>";
$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "<tr height='100'>";
$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "<td bgcolor='#5BA7FF' align='center'>";
$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "<h3 style='color:#FFF; font-family:Verdana;'>Welcome to International Center for Islamic Finance & Business</h3>";
$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "</td>";
$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "</tr>";

$EmailBody.=$EmailBodyParam;        

$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "<br />";
$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "<h4 style='font-family:Verdana; font-size:13px;'>Regards,</h4>";
$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "<p style='font-family:Verdana; font-size:12px; text-align:justify; line-height: 20px;'>ICIFB | Finance Department</p>";
$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "</td>";
$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "</tr>";
$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "<tr height='50'>";
$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "<td bgcolor='#62B54F' align='center'>";
$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "<h2 style='color:#FFF; font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana; font-weight:normal;'>Copyright &copy; 2015 | International Center for Islamic Finance & Business</h2>";
$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "</td>";
$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "</tr>";
$EmailBody  = $EmailBody . "</table>";

    // Send Email

$success = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n"; 
$success.= "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n"; 
$success.= "X-Priority: 3\r\n"; 
$success.= "X-Mailer: smail-PHP ".phpversion()."\r\n";
$success = mail($receiver, $Subject, $EmailBody, "From: $sendername<$sender>\nReply-To: $sender\nContent-Type: text/html");
return $success;
}
}
```

Comment: new Email its your custom class or some non standard library. We cannot know what is wrong with it

Comment: What is the code for `// Prepare Email Body Text` and `// Prepare Email Body2 Text` ?

Comment: None of the $EmailBody, $EmailBody2 variables are assigned a value in the above code. So it seems that you are trying to send an empty email to the recipients. Either show us the code where these variables are assigned any value or assign them value.

Comment: @Daimos yes it is my custome class, i'm updating my question, please see

Comment: @Kuya this is for email body, i just removed it because it was too lengthy

Comment: Sending the email is your problem... correct? We need to see the code that formulates and sends the email.

Comment: @Kuya i just update my question please see the below code

Comment: What does `$EmailBodyParam` contain? I will presume that it contains information from a DB query regarding the payment/transaction. If an error occurs there, the code breaks.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: it contains the remaining part of the email body, which is different for both receiver, but i'm not getting the mail not even blank mail

Comment: let me explain again in simple words.... user will paid his remaining amount... record is updating in database and then i want to send an email to both user and admin with latest payment details... everything is working fine except emails...

Comment: hope u r getting my point

Comment: I get your point. The update functions fine. The email is not sent. That's why I'm concentrating my questions regarding how the email is formulated and sent. That's what we need to see. If an error occurs ANYWHERE inside the code for formulating and sending the email (including `$EmailBodyParam`) the email will not be sent.

Comment: Have you checked your error logs to see what's going on?

Comment: i just share my all code.... see the latest update in email body... that's all i have

Comment: not getting any error in error_log

Comment: ps you know that you can write only $EmailBody  .= "<br />"; instead of repeat it twice? ;)

Comment: server sending mails ? Checked with simple mail function?

Comment: well that was my first try :) did you found any isuue?